# Javascript REGEX: Ignore anything in between?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I ignore anything in between with Javascript RegEx?

For example, I want to detect all three words: `how` `are` `you` in that order.

My regex:

```
var pattern = /([how]+[are]+[you]+)/i;

pattern.test("howare"); //false <--- expected (correct)
pattern.test("areyou"); //false <--- expected (correct)
pattern.test("howareyou"); //true <--- expected (correct)
pattern.test(" howareyou! "); //true <--- expected (correct)
pattern.test("how are  you"); //false <--- this should match!
pattern.test("how areyou  "); //false <--- this should match!
```

But then I want to ignore anything in between them.

Comment: I'm sorry if you confused. Edited the question a bit now.

Comment: That does help clarify (though I'd assumed that was the case in my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to add a wildcard in between your words by using

```
.* // 0 or more of any character
```

Regex rules are by default greedy, so trying to match `are` will take precedence over `.*`.

To note however you need to take out your square brackets as they'll currently allow things to match that shouldn't. For example they would allow `hooooowareyou` to match, as the square brackets allow all of the given characters, and the `+` indicates 1 or more.

Try something like:

```
how.*are.*you
```

It's unclear if you want all your test cases to pass, if you do then here's an example of this answer in action https://regex101.com/r/aTTU5b/2

Comment: I'm sorry if you confused. Edited the question a bit now.

Comment: `To note however you don't need your square brackets.` -> it's not only that they are not needed, they do also cause harm (with OP pattern `hay` would match)

Comment: @SebastianProske yeah that's true. I'll modify my answer to make that clearer

Comment: @Aaron, no `.*` is not lazy...unless a particular language's implementation works differently. Every language I've used/seen is greedy by default.

Comment: @Aaron nope, they are greedy, but backtrack if needed in order to match. So the first `.*` will match to the end of the string and then backtrack until `are` can be matched.

Comment: Why `.*` isn't put after `you` also, please? Shouldn't it be like: `how.*are.*you.*`? Sorry for my dumb question, bcos i got no idea about regex. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, so both lazy and greedy `.*` would work : using the greedy `.*` makes `.` match until the end of the text then backtrack until `are` can match, while using the lazy `.*?` makes it try to match `are` after each character matched by `.` ; in any case `are` takes precedence only because if it wasn't matched the pattern would fail, not because of greediness or laziness

Comment: @Aaron yes, in order to match a pattern, a regex will give up greedyness (and backtrack) or lazyness (and expand). I don't know if you can actually call that a precedence for `are`.

Comment: @夏期劇場 yes you can put `.*` if you want to capture things after `you`. The reason I didn't do this is because unless you specify the `you$` you're not enforcing the the string end at `you` - just that it's contained within it.

Comment: @SebastianProske I was quoting the answer's second sentence, which I consider incorrect. I agree it's not a preference, it's just that if every fragment of the regex that is mandatory (has no quantifier accepting 0 occurrence) must be matched for the whole pattern to be matched.

Comment: @Ian , thank you for the answer. (I'm not sure but i see your answer is shorter. Thats why accepted) . If possible, PLEASE HELP with my another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786926/javascript-regex-to-allow-only-specific-characters-with-a-bit-of-addition-cond

Comment: @ 夏期劇場 shorter doesn't always mean better. e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118750/find-the-nearest-greater-number

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
how.*?are.*?you
```

This will ensure that **how**, **are** and **you** are present in the same order and ignore any characters in-between. So it will return a match for `howwww areee!#%@!$%$#% you?` etc. Check out more positive and negative cases using the demo link below:

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rzhkHC/3

Comment: I'm sorry if you confused. Edited the question a bit now.

Comment: But it also ensures that `however`, and `hare`, and `bayou` are present.

Comment: Why use the `?` - doesn't it accomplish the same as `*`?

Comment: @Ian I wanted it to be lazy so that if `howareyou how are you` is present then it will extract both separately. However that isn't something the OP is trying to achieve I think

Comment: @KennethK. what do you mean by *ensuring `however` and `hare` are present?*. I didn't quite get how the regex does that?

Comment: The OP says "words". Is `how` a word if it is part of `however`? Your pattern yields success if `however` is in the target string. OP needs to clarify if he truly wants words.

Comment: Aah, got it. Yes, that's right, it definitely could do with a bit more clarity. The current regex solution only ensures that they are present in the specific order and nothing else

Comment: Why `.*?` isn't put after `you` also, please? Shouldn't it be like: `how.*?are.*?you.*?` like that? Sorry for my dumb question, bcos i got no idea about regex. Thanks.

Comment: You can add it but if your objective is just to *make sure the three words are present in the given* then it is unnecessary since adding it at the end will make it match any characters after `you` such as `howareyou1234` will have all the 1234 also selected in the match

Comment: Dear Downvoter, how about sharing some insight into how I can avoid making the same mistake in the future? Thanks!

Comment: @degant nope, the `.*?` at the end of a pattern will always match an empty string (remember it is lazy) - except when used in the context of a function that requires a full match (not sure if there is any in JS)

Comment: @SebastianProske Wow, completely missed that point. Good catch :). So it will not matching anything since it is at the end. But it doesn't behave the same way when it is at the start (like this `.*?how.*?are`), does it?

Comment: @degant Regex also matches from the leftmost position it can, so `.*?` will always expand from the start of the string to the first position where `how` can be matched properly.