# Javascript REGEX: To allow ONLY specific characters, with a bit of addition conditions?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say i want to catch a string, with following **conditions**:

- ONLY these four specific characters are allowed: `h`,`i`,,`!`
- Any of them can appear multiple times
- String MUST start with `h`
- *(Most importantly)* `h` and `i` MUST present together (as `hi`) at least 1 time.

Therefore, **accepted** (expected) ones could be:

- `hi`
- `hi!`
- `hhi !!`
- `h ihi !`

**Non-acceptable**, for example:

- `ih!` <-- becos: no `hi`
- `h i` <-- becos: no `hi` (together)
- `!hi` <-- becos: didn't start with `h`
- `hi! x` <-- becos: external character(s)

Here is what i tried so far:

```
var pattern = /^[h]+[i]+[ !]*/i;

pattern.test("hi"); //true <--- expected (correct)
pattern.test("hiiih !"); //true <--- expected (correct)
pattern.test("ihi"); //false <--- expected (correct)
pattern.test(" hi"); //false <--- expected (correct)
pattern.test("hixx"); //true <--- not expected (wrong)
```

(Which means (so far) i can do all i need, but cannot do characters restrictions.)

May be my whole REGEX should be corrected into different approach. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the regex:

```
^(?=h)[hi !]*hi[hi !]*$
```

- `^(?=h)`: the begin of the string must be followed by an `h`
- `[hi !]*`: only the character class `[hi !]` is acepted
- `hi`: at some point there is "hi"
- `[hi !]*$`: continue with the character class `[hi !]` until reaching the end

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/s7wusm/1)

Comment: Wow it works!! (Is it the shortest it can be, please?) :D

Comment: @夏期劇場 I guess so

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = /^h+i+[hi !]*$/i;
```

The pattern must start with 1 or more 'h', followed by 1 or more 'i', then can contain 'hi !' in any quantity up to the end of the string.

Comment: `h!hi` and `h hi` don't match

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't satisfy `hh hihi!`

Answer (score 0):

Using a small lookahead and assertion for h at the beginning.

```
(?=.*hi)^h[hi !]+$
```

[JSFiddle](https://regex101.com/r/aNNjAw/2)